# Batch script: remove Japanese character from filename in Windows

Tags: batch-file, set, character, non-english

I am trying to make my batch recognize and remove non-English characters. Basically any characters that appear as a "?" in the cmd window. Do I need to use VBScript?

I am at the point where I am considering brute force writing a script that extracts every letter of the filename and compares it against a huge list of acceptable characters, but there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a (`dir /b`) do (
:: Change the above line to `dir /s /b` to include subdirectories
set var=%%~a 
if "!var:?=!" neq "%%~a" (ren "%%~a" "!var:?=!")
)
```

And that will remove all `?`s in file names in the current directory (unless you include `/s`). Note it will not work if your file names starts with a `;`. But I'm guessing that will not cause a problem.

Comment: Mona.  Thanks but I already tried character replacement with the question mark.  but it turns out that the question mark is only a representation of an unprintable character.  it is not actually a "?" that I am trying to remove. file names cant even have a "?" in them anyway.  I think this is a real stumper.     I assume the Ascii codes for japanese characters are higher than 255.  if there is a way to check each characters ascii code then maybe that would work?

Comment: If thats what you need, what you could do is output all files into a textfile, get a python file to remove any characters of ASCII greater the 255 and then rename all files with the names in the new files.